# Javascript (jQuery) post to PHP, empty properties not parsed

Tags: ajax, jquery

i have a javascript object declared something like:

```
var myObject = {"a":{"b": "c", "d": "e"}, "f":{"g":{}, "h":{}}};
```

I'm using jQuery's

```
$.post(url, myObject, function(){});
```

to send the data to my php file. for some reason, the empty properties are not being passed, so, because "g" and "h" are empty, even "f" is not passed in the post.

Is there any way i can include them without filling it with bogus data?

thanks

Comment: What does the php code look like?  That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: i don't think it's got anything to do with php, because using firebug or chrome's inspector, i see the data that is posted, and i don't have those properties before the server

Comment: If you check [jQuery bug 6481](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6481), you'll see that including the parameters was considered bad behavior, mostly because the HTTP protocol really can't represent the concept of "empty object" as a parameter value.

Comment: i understand that, but using my colleague's library, where he is using common XHR/activex for posting, everything goes out the way it should. I agree that it isn't a bug from jQuery but i really needed this and i had to go somewhere else. thanks a lot then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is not with JavaScript.  When you call "$.post()" like that, your object will be turned into a HTTP query form with the equivalent of "$.param":

```
var params = $.param({"a":{"b": "c", "d": "e"}, "f":{"g":{}, "h":{}}});
```

That string looks like:

> a%5Bb%5D=c&a%5Bd%5D=e&f%5Bg%5D=&f%5Bh%5D=

which, decoded, is:

> a[b]=c&a[d]=e&f[g]=&f[h]=

---

**edit** — well that's odd.  Internally, jQuery is indeed setting up the parameters as I wrote above, but for whatever reason Firefox is stripping out the empty ones.  If I add a "beforeSend" handler, it's clear that the parameters are all there, those with values as well as those without. However, when the actual HTTP request goes out, they're gone.

You could attach the parameters to the URL if you don't mind them going out on the wire that way.

Comment: ok, i can understand that, but that's not really an answer to my question. can you think of a solution? thanks

Comment: I realize it's not an answer, except that it explains that you've got a different problem than what you think you've got. If you post some of the php code from the server end of the transaction, the real problem might become clear.

Comment: i don't think it's got anything to do with php, because using firebug or chrome's inspector, i see the data that is posted, and i don't have those properties before the server

Comment: thanks for everything. a colleague of mine gave me access to a XHR library he built for some other things, and the request goes out as it should. unfortunately, this is closed source, so i can not post the answer.